# whenever gem: when work starts for the first time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

In my `schedule.rb` file I have the following lines:

```
every 6.day, :at => "9:00am" do
  runner "my_function"
end
```

When my function starts for the first time?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the actual cron generated content using this command in your rails root directory :

```
whenever
```

Using a line like the one you provided, this gives this to me :

```
0 9 1,7,13,19,25 * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd path && script/rails runner -e production '\''my_function'\'''
```

Which means the task is ran the 1th, 7th, 13th, 19th and 25th, at 9:00.

Answer (score 0):

So, it will run on every 6th day from begining of the month @ 9 AM